# New Elements added to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm coding a webpage using CSS and PHP. Whenever I add a new element it's pushed down to the bottom of the page. I thought it was a one time thing only affecting a paragraph so I added negative margins for it (not great practice, I know), but every element I add is getting pushed to the end of the page and I have to scroll to find it.

The paragraph below was the part getting pushed down, the login heading remained at the top, but when I tried adding more text after, it got pushed down as well.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Urbanist:wght@500&display=swap');
* {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: -740; //I added negative margins because this element was being pushed downwards and that solved it, but I don't want to have to do it with every new element. 
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #1e3799;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  right: 30%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-syle: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #1e3799;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #4a69bd;
}
```

```html
<h1>Log In</h1>
<p> No Account?<a href="register.php">Register here!</p>
```

Comment: I think you should remove this part `*{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}` This will adjust every element, change it to `*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}` so all widths, margins and paddings will be placed correct

Comment: There is no need for PHP here. It is a CSS issue only

Comment: Your welcome, I whant to advise you to order your css a bit better start with the `*` then the `body` and `footer` at the end. In your example you declare the body styling now twice. `SASS` or `LESS` are great imo to group your styling nice and clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use width and height 100% for *.
This `*` means use it every element on

```css
p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: -740; /* You forgot to add 'px' here */
}
```

Change this to these to full page with preserving background color.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You also forgot to close `<p> No Account?<a href="register.php">Register here!</a></p>` tag.

I don't suggest you use this if you don't know what you are doing `line-height: 0px;`

Here is complete fixed code. I aligned some items because the way of coding I thought you want to center footer items.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  /* line-height: 0px; */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* line-height: 0px; */
  /* margin-top: -740; */
  /* You forgot to add 'px' here */
}

body {
  background-color: #4a69bd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #1e3799;
}

footer, p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  color: white;
  font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
}

a {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Log In</h1>
  <footer>
    <p> No Account?<a href="register.php">Register here!</a></p>
  </footer>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have given all (*) a height of 100% in your css

Comment: Like I said 30 minutes ago in the comment I posted

Comment: Comments aren't answers. If you wanted to post an answer, you should have done.